# Solve homogeneous system

Tags: equation-solving

Let

x^2*y + x^2*z + x*y^2 + y^2*z + x*z^2 + y*z^2+ x*y*z =0

x^3-x*y*z + x^2*y-x*y*z + x^2*z-x*y*z + x*y^2-x*y*z - x*y*z+y^2*z - x*y*z+x*z^2 - x*y*z+y*z^2 =0

x^3+3*x*y*z+7*y*z^2 +  x*y*z+y^3+9*y*z^2 +  x^2*y+6*x*y*z+4*y*z^2 + x^2*z+x*y*z+9*y*z^2 +  x*y^2-y*z^2 + 3*x*y*z+y^2*z+7*y*z^2 + 6*x*y*z+x*z^2+4*y*z^2=0

x^3+x*y*z+7*x*z^2+2*y*z^2 + x*y*z+y^3+9*y*z^2 + 8*x*y*z+7*x*z^2+6*y*z^2+z^3 + x^2*y+7*x*y*z+2*x*z^2+y*z^2 + x^2*z+7*x*y*z+x*z^2+2*y*z^2 +  x*y^2+4*x*y*z+8*x*z^2+9*y*z^2 +  5*x*y*z+4*x*z^2+y^2*z+y*z^2=0

is a homogeneous linear system .

How can solve this system?

I wrote

```
sys = 
  {x^2*y + x^2*z + x*y^2 + y^2*z + x*z^2 + y*z^2 + x*y*z = 0

   x^3 - x*y*z + x^2*y - x*y*z + x^2*z - x*y*z + x*y^2 - x*y*z - x*y*z + y^2*z - x*y*z + x*z^2 - x*y*z + y*z^2 = 0

   x^3 + 3*x*y*z + 7*y*z^2 + x*y*z + y^3 + 9*y*z^2 +  x^2*y + 6*x*y*z + 4*y*z^2 + x^2*z + x*y*z + 9*y*z^2 + x*y^2 - y*z^2 + 3*x*y*z + y^2*z + 7*y*z^2 + 6*x*y*z + x*z^2 + 4*y*z^2 = 0

   x^3 + x*y*z + 7*x*z^2 + 2*y*z^2 + x*y*z + y^3 + 9*y*z^2 + 8*x*y*z + 7*x*z^2 + 6*y*z^2 + z^3 + x^2*y + 7*x*y*z + 2*x*z^2 + y*z^2 + x^2*z + 7*x*y*z + x*z^2 + 2*y*z^2 + x*y^2 + 4*x*y*z + 8*x*z^2 + 9*y*z^2 +  5*x*y*z + 4*x*z^2 + y^2*z + y*z^2 = 0}
```

and then I have used

```
Solve[
  x^2*y + x^2*z + x*y^2 + y^2*z + x*z^2 + y*z^2 + x*y*z,
  x^3 - x*y*z + x^2*y - x*y*z + x^2*z-x*y*z + x*y^2 - x*y*z - x*y*z+y^2*z - x*y*z+x*z^2 - x*y*z + y*z^2,
  x^3 + 3*x*y*z + 7*y*z^2 + x*y*z + y^3 + 9*y*z^2 + x^2*y + 6*x*y*z + 4*y*z^2 + x^2*z + x*y*z + 9*y*z^2 + x*y^2 - y*z^2 + 3*x*y*z + y^2*z + 7*y*z^2 + 6*x*y*z + x*z^2  + 4*y*z^2,
  x^3 + x*y*z + 7*x*z^2 + 2*y*z^2 + x*y*z + y^3 + 9*y*z^2 + 8*x*y*z + 7*x*z^2 + 6*y*z^2 + z^3 + x^2*y + 7*x*y*z + 2*x*z^2 + y*z^2 + x^2*z + 7*x*y*z + x*z^2 + 2*y*z^2 + x*y^2 + 4*x*y*z + 8*x*z^2 + 9*y*z^2 +  5*x*y*z + 4*x*z^2 + y^2*z + y*z^2]
```

Comment: 1. That ain't linear. 2. `xyz` and `x y z` are two very different things: one is a symbol, and the other is three multiplied symbols.

Comment: Reduce[sys,{x,y,z}] with all the * inserted and all the = replaced with == almost instantly returns x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0 as the only solution.

Comment: I did that but no result

Answer (score 3):

Too long to fit in a comment without turning * into italics and my comment wasn't enough for the OP to be able to reproduce this. So...

Starting with a new fresh notebook with no previous assignments and copy-n-paste exactly this into your notebook

```
sys = {x^2*y + x^2*z + x*y^2 + y^2*z + x*z^2 + y*z^2 + x*y*z == 0,
       x^3 - x*y*z + x^2*y - x*y*z + x^2*z - x*y*z + x*y^2 - x*y*z -
         x*y*z + y^2*z - x*y*z + x*z^2 - x*y*z + y*z^2 == 0, 
       x^3 + 3*x*y*z + 7*y*z^2 + x*y*z + y^3 + 9*y*z^2 + x^2*y + 
         6*x*y*z + 4*y*z^2 + x^2*z + x*y*z + 9*y*z^2 + x*y^2 - y*z^2 + 
         3*x*y*z + y^2*z + 7*y*z^2 + 6*x*y*z + x*z^2 + 4*y*z^2 == 0, 
       x^3 + x*y*z + 7*x*z^2 + 2*y*z^2 + x*y*z + y^3 + 9*y*z^2 + 
         8*x*y*z + 7*x*z^2 + 6*y*z^2 + z^3 + x^2*y + 7*x*y*z + 2*x*z^2 + 
         y*z^2 + x^2*z + 7*x*y*z + x*z^2 + 2*y*z^2 + x*y^2 + 4*x*y*z + 
         8*x*z^2 + 9*y*z^2 + 5*x*y*z + 4*x*z^2 + y^2*z + y*z^2 == 0};
Reduce[sys, {x, y, z}]
```

followed by shift+enter then almost instantly returns

```
x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0
```

as the only solution.

I would expect this to take far longer. Notice if you subtract equation 4 from equation 3 you get a much smaller equation and if you subtract equation 2 from equation 3 you get a much smaller equation. That explains some of why you get an instant result.

Because the system is so simple, Solve is equally capable of finding the same solution.